# select row in heavy csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

i search how can i select some row with word in line so i use this script

```
import pandas
import datetime


df = pandas.read_csv(
    r"C:StockEtablissement_utf8(1)\StockEtablissement_utf8.csv",
    sep=",",
)


communes = ["PERPIGNAN"]


print()

df = df[~df["libelleCommuneEtablissement"].isin(communes)]

print()
```

so my script work well with a normal csv

but with a heavy Csv (4Go) the scipt say :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:lafinessedufiness.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pandas.read_csv(r'C:StockEtablissement_utf8(1)\StockEtablissement_utf8.csv',
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 581, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1250, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 225, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 805, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 883, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1026, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1072, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1172, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1731, in pandas._libs.parsers._try_int64
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 128. KiB for an array with shape (16384,) and data type int64
```

do you know how can i fix this error please?

Comment: The two lowest-effort things you can do: (1) You're using a 32-bit version of Python. Switch to a 64-bit version if your hardware supports it. (2) Buy and install more memory in your machine.

Comment: No, the lowest effort thing you can do is stream read the file line using the `csv` module.

Comment: @JonSG That's not low-effort for someone who wants to use Pandas's API, e.g. `df[x].isin(...)`.

Comment: The post is tagged pandas likely as that is the first attempt. No place in the post (though I admit it is brief) is it stated. "I need/want to use pandas". On the contrary, the post seeks to find a given row. You are turning it into an X/Y problem based on a good faith effort on the part of the user to solve their issue. Let's ask specifically.

Comment: Is `pandas` required as part of your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`pd.read_csv()` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has an option to read the file in chunks, rather than loading it all at once.  Use `iterator=True` and specify a reasonable chunk size (rows per chunk).

```py
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:StockEtablissement_utf8(1)\StockEtablissement_utf8.csv'
it = pd.read_csv(path, sep=',', iterator=True, chunksize=10_000)

communes = ['PERPIGNAN']

filtered_chunks = []
for chunk_df in it:
    chunk_df = chunk_df.query('libelleCommuneEtablissement not in @communes')
    filtered_chunks.append(chunk_df)

df = pd.concat(filtered_chunks)
```

Comment: hi and thanks for your help sadly that's don't work, i've got the same message like before

Comment: The strange thing here is that the actual error you quoted above refers to a very small amount of memory: `128 KiB`.  Such a small allocation surely isn't causing you to run out of RAM.  Something strange is going on.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you don't have enough memory available for Pandas to load that file entirely into memory.

One reason is that based on `Python38-32` in the traceback, you're running a 32-bit version of Python, where 4 gigabytes (or is it 3 gigabytes?) is the limit for memory allocations anyway. If your system is 64-bit, you should switch to the 64-bit version of Python, so that's one obstacle less.

If that doesn't help, you'll just also need more memory. You could configure Windows's virtual memory, or buy more actual memory and install it in your system.

If those don't help, then you'll have to come up with a better approach than to load the big CSV entirely into memory.

For one, if you really only care about rows with the string `PERPIGNAN` (no matter the column; you can really filter it again in your code), you could do `grep PERPIGNAN data.csv > data_perpignan.csv` and work with that (assuming you have `grep`; you can do the same filtering with a short Python script).

Since `read_csv()` accepts any iterable of lines, you can also just do something like

```
def lines_from_file_including_strings(file, strings):
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        if i == 0 or any(string in line for string in strings):
            yield line


communes = ["PERPIGNAN", "PARIS"]

with open("StockEtablissement_utf8.csv") as f:
  df = pd.read_csv(lines_from_file_including_strings(f, communes), sep=",")
```

for an initial filter.

Comment: ok thanks in reality i research 36 words but for my test i just search 1 word

Comment: The other answer could be closer to what you want, then. But be sure to use a 64-bit Python nevertheless.

Comment: The OP's code doesn't search for the presence of `PERPIGNAN`.  It actually searches for its absence (note the `~` character).  So something like `grep -vE "PERPIGNAN|OTHER_WORD|OTHER_WORD2"` would be necessary.  But then it really matters that the search terms will never appear in other columns -- filtering within his Python script is not an option at that point.

Comment: Iterating over the lines one-by-one as suggested here will be very slow for a 4GB file.  It will be much more efficient to use `pd.read_csv` to load the file in moderately large chunks, and rely on pandas' vectorized filtering implementation.